# Implementar JWT en aplicacion Nodejs + Angular + MySQL en TypeScript

Tags: mysql, nodejs, angular, typescript, jwt

He desarrollado una aplicación en **Nodejs** junto con **Angular**, tanto backend como frontend en lenguaje **TypeScript** y sacando datos de **MySQL** con la librería promise-mysql. Mi problema surge al querer integrar **JWT** para la autenticación de usuarios ya que no se como hacerlo o cuales son las practicas correctas para ello. Tengo entendido que se utiliza **Sequelizer** para ello, pero desconozco su implementación en el contexto de mi proyecto.

Comment: Te invito a repasar [ask]. Tal como está, tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: He intentado buscar como implementar sequelizer pero solo sabia en formato js y no en TypeScript. Pero como digo, no estoy muy familiarizado con nodejs y sus librerias asi que no se si es correcto utilizar sequelizer para llegar a mi objetivo que es implmenetar JWT

Comment: JWT no depende de ningún ORM/ODM, no necesitas `Sequelize` para usar JWT. Por otro lado, existen infinidad de tutoriales que te pueden orientar en cómo implementar JWT en tu proyecto. Por ejemplo [este](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/creating-a-rest-api-with-jwt-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-using-typescript-fbfa3cab22a4). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

JWT es una libreria independiente a sequelize. No necesitas usar sequelize para utilizar JWT. Lo primero que debes hacer es integrar la libreria JWT a tu desarrollo node.
Puedes hacerlo en tu Controller, asi:

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

creado el objeto jwt, dispones de un conjunto de metodo y/o funciones nativas de la libreria, como son:
jwt.sign
A esta funcion le pasas los datos con los que quieres crear el token.
Ejemplo:
const accessToken = jwt.sign({username:data[0].username, role:data[0].role},accessTokenSecret);

accessTokenSecret: es una key secreto de la aplicacion.

Para finalizar almacenas accessToken y el id del usuario que ha hecho login